# MYSQL: Condition based on the same table, the same value in a different column

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, inner-join, self-join

I have a table `administ` (administrations) containing 4 columns `adm_nr`, `pres_name` (president name), `year` and `vice_pres` (vice president name).
I need to select the `vice_pres` and the amount of times they are featured in the table.

Here is my SQL

```
SELECT vice_pres, COUNT(vice_pres)
FROM administ
GROUP BY vice_pres
```

The problem is that there is an extra condition, being I only want to see the results (names & count) for vice presidents who've also been president. So there is a value comparison between two columns of the same table, in which the value for vice_pres (the name of the vice president), needs to be equal to at least one value for pres_name in another row but within the same table (in that he's been president at some point).

I'm thinking there's going to be an self join situation but can't for the life 
of me figure out how to pen down this condition.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "vice presidents who've also been president", how can this be determined? Show the relevant fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join table with itself to select only those who was president

```
SELECT t.vice_pres, COUNT(t.vice_pres)
FROM administ t join administ p on t.vice_pres=p.pres_name
GROUP BY t.vice_pres
```